# Count how many distinct values (or get list of distinct values) in a filtered column

Tags: excel

Is there a way to count the number of distinct values in a **filtered** column in Excel?

Using the formula at https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif I can count the number of distinct values in a range, but when that range has been filtered with an auto-filter I still get the unfiltered count.

For example:

```
     A          B
1    Scarf      Blue
2    Hat        Red
3    Gloves     Green
4    Coat       Blue
5    Balloon    Red
6    Shoes      Blue
```

Counting unique values in B with `=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B6<>"") / COUNTIF(B1:B6,B1:B6 & ""))` should return `3` as the distinct values are `Red`, `Green` and `Blue`.

If I auto filter Column B to just select `Red` items, the resulting table will look like:

```
     A          B
2    Hat        Red
5    Balloon    Red
```

In this case the number of distinct values retuned should be `1`. But the formula above still returns `3`.

The formula should also cope with multiple selections in the auto-filter, so for example filtering for `Blue` and `Green` should result in the following table:

```
     A          B
1    Scarf      Blue
3    Gloves     Green
4    Coat       Blue
6    Shoes      Blue
```

From which the formula should return `2` (Blue, Green).

Finally, if I am filtering on column `A` rather than `B`, the formula should still work. So If I am only interested in `Hat`, `Scarf` and `Coat`, filtering column `A` for these values would result in:

```
     A          B
1    Scarf      Blue
2    Hat        Red
4    Coat       Blue
```

From which the formula should return `2`.

(I'm using Excel 2013 and need to do this in a formula rather than using VBA etc)

I also found [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-7889942d-824e-4469-893c-191d1efde950?CorrelationId=166b86e4-5f31-48ea-8d86-d48d3ab1ec06&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP010070481) on office.com which I thought might help, but alas I can't get it to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reference shows how you can exclude hidden rows using AGGREGATE

[Excluding hidden rows with AGGREGATE](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/visible-column-in-excel-tables.htm)

You can then use a standard way of counting unique values like this

[Counting unique values with FREQUENCY](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273)

So if you were counting values in column B, you would need a helper column (say C) containing

```
=IF(AGGREGATE(3,5,B2),B2,"")
```

Then plug in the form of count unique that ignores empty cells

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(C2:C10)>0,MATCH(C2:C10,C2:C10,0),""), IF(LEN(C2:C10)>0,MATCH(C2:C10,C2:C10,0),""))>0,1))
```

Or your formula if you prefer

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C10<>"") / COUNTIF(C2:C10,C2:C10 & ""))
```