# Excel formula to count non empty cells in a column for distinct values in an other column

Tags: excel, count

I have a list of members in Excel with their date of deaths (date of death not populated, if member is still alive). For one member there can be more lines because there can be more benefit lines associated. I would like to count the number of distinct members who are dead.
[An example of my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc4a5.png)

As a result, I would like to get 2, the count of distinct dead members in my list.

Comment: Have you considered countif() or countifs()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count how many distinct values (or get list of distinct values) in a filtered column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591391/count-how-many-distinct-values-or-get-list-of-distinct-values-in-a-filtered-co)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can benefit from SUMPRODUCT:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9&B2:B9<>"")/COUNTIFS(A2:A9;A2:A9&"";B2:B9;B2:B9&"");--(B2:B9<>""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2021 supports the dynamic array functions.

You can compose `FILTER`, `UNIQUE` and `COUNT` functions.

IF your IDs are in column A and the dates are in column B.

1. `FILTER` out items in column A, when the column B is *Truthy* (non-empty).
2. Apply the `UNIQUE` function.
3. Apply the `COUNT` function.

The following formula will produce the count of unique IDs with non-empty dates:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,B:B)))
```